# how can I stop a thread in producer and consumer in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

this is my consumer class

I cant know how can I stop a thread until a product will be produced?
(the sleep seems not work sometimes)

please suggest me a way other than the blocking queue interface and sleep method

```
package producerconsumer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    Thread t;
    String consumerName;

    public Consumer(String name) {
        t = new Thread(this, name);
        t.start();

    }

    @Override
    public  void run() {
        int m = Producer_consumer.n;
        try {
            if (m!=0) {
                Producer_consumer.delay.acquire();
            } else {
                Thread.sleep(100);//??
            }

            while (true) {
                Producer_consumer.criticalSection.acquire();
                consumerName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                consume();
                Producer_consumer.n--;
                Producer_consumer.form.setLable(Producer_consumer.n + "");
                m = Producer_consumer.n;
                Producer_consumer.criticalSection.release();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sleep is a code smell, but why don't you want to use an implementation of BlockingQueue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait() for a condition and notify() when the condition has changed. Here is an example taken from:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

```
public class Drop {
    // Message sent from producer
    // to consumer.
    private String message;
    // True if consumer should wait
    // for producer to send message,
    // false if producer should wait for
    // consumer to retrieve message.
    private boolean empty = true;

    public synchronized String take() {
        // Wait until message is
        // available.
        while (empty) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        // Toggle status.
        empty = true;
        // Notify producer that
        // status has changed.
        notifyAll();
        return message;
    }

    public synchronized void put(String message) {
        // Wait until message has
        // been retrieved.
        while (!empty) {
            try { 
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        // Toggle status.
        empty = false;
        // Store message.
        this.message = message;
        // Notify consumer that status
        // has changed.
        notifyAll();
    }
```

Comment: @EngineerDollery I've quoted the code from the source. Is the answer acceptable now?